# How to access the raw input text and the entire conversation in AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-lex, aws-lex

1. How can I access to raw text the lead to the intent in lex
2. How can I extract the entire conversation including the user input and the Lex responses

I thought of creating a lambda & API gateway to capture the input and record it before sending it to Lex , and on each intent lambda record the response , but seems like a round about way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In the `event` which you receive in Lambda function, you can get raw text from `inputTranscript`

> {'messageVersion': '1.0', 'invocationSource': 'DialogCodeHook', 'userId': '', 'sessionAttributes': {}, 'requestAttributes': {}, 'bot':
>   {'name': 'bot_name', 'alias': 'bot_alias', 'version': '$LATEST'},
>   'outputDialogMode': 'Text', **'currentIntent': {'name':
>   'invoked_intent_name'**, 'slots': {}, 'slotDetails': {},
>   'confirmationStatus': 'None'}, **'inputTranscript': 'user message which
>   triggered the intent'**}

2. For storing the conversation, in the Lambda function, just before you provide the response to the user, you can write a function to store the conversation i.e user query and response from bot.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

1. The raw text that matched your intent can be reference as `event.inputTranscript` The full event format is [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html).
2. Amazon has a great example of how to build out a transcript of the entire conversation.  Take a look at the [RideService example code](https://www.connectdemo.com/references/lexLambdaRideService.html).  Pay attention to how `appendTranscript` is used to build the full transcript of the interaction.